# When using a timeline, how to add a checkbox in each resource cells that emit a custom Vue event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I want to customize the resource cells in the following way :

- I want to be able to have a checkbox before the resource name
- I want to emit a custom Vue event when a checkbox is checked or unchecked.

I tried to bind the following on the resource-render prop :

```
 resourceRender: (renderInfo: any) => {
    const checkBox = document.createElement('input');
    checkBox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
        if (checkBox.checked) {
            this.$emit('resource-checked', renderInfo.resource);
        } else {
            this.$emit('resource-unchecked', renderInfo.resource);
        }
    });
    renderInfo.el.querySelector('.fc-cell-text').prepend(checkBox);
}
```

The checkbox is correctly added, but the when I click on it, I've got 
this error :

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:3857 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resource-checked' of undefined
at SgsResourceTimeline.Vue.$emit (vue.runtime.esm.js:3857)
at SgsResourceTimeline.Vue.<computed> [as $emit] (backend.js:1793)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (sgs-resource-timeline.ts:73)
```

With the following VueJS code where the error happens being :

```
Vue.prototype.$emit = function (event) {
    var vm = this;
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      var lowerCaseEvent = event.toLowerCase();
      if (lowerCaseEvent !== event && vm._events[lowerCaseEvent]) {
        tip(
          "Event \"" + lowerCaseEvent + "\" is emitted in component " +
          (formatComponentName(vm)) + " but the handler is registered for \"" + event + "\". " +
          "Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and you cannot use " +
          "v-on to listen to camelCase events when using in-DOM templates. " +
          "You should probably use \"" + (hyphenate(event)) + "\" instead of \"" + event + "\"."
        );
      }
    }
    // THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES
    // event is equal to resource-checked
    // vm._events is undefined
    var cbs = vm._events[event];
    if (cbs) {
      cbs = cbs.length > 1 ? toArray(cbs) : cbs;
      var args = toArray(arguments, 1);
      var info = "event handler for \"" + event + "\"";
      for (var i = 0, l = cbs.length; i < l; i++) {
        invokeWithErrorHandling(cbs[i], vm, args, vm, info);
      }
    }
    return vm
   };
```

What am I doing wrong, or how should I do this ?

Comment: Please read why you [should not post screenshots of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: Edited according to your recommendation